# AJAX no me envía, ni me coge los datos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax, php7

Compañeros, esta vez necesito ayuda, debido a que tengo 2 problemas:

1. AJAX no me toma el texto escrito en el input con id='bus1'.
2. AJAX no me envía ningún dato, por lo que me aparece el error de índices indefinidos al lamar pedir.php.

A continuación, dejo el código que uso. En el comentario, está el código real para que tengan visión clara, pero se ejecutará un HTML de ejemplo.

```js
function obtener_datos(){
    $.ajax({                        
        type:"POST",                 
        url:"pedir.php",
        success: function(data)             
        {
            $('#categorias').html(data);               
        }
    });
}
$(document).on("keyup", "#bus1", function(){
  event.preventDefault();
        var data=$(this).text(); 
        var ficha=$(this).data("bus1");
        alert(data);
        alert(ficha);
        $.ajax({                        
        type:"POST",                 
        url:"pedir.php",
        data:{id:ficha},
        success: function(data)             
        {
            obtener_datos();               
        }
    });
})
```

```css
      #muestreo{
  position:absolute;
  top:1%;
  width:81%;
  left:19%;
  margin:center;
  z-index:100;
}
.titulos{
  width:6%;
  height:20%;
  background-color:#238276;
  color:#ffffff;
}
.generalidades{
  width:15%;
  text-align:center;
  max-width:1000px;
}
.immg{
  width:0.1%;
}
#producto{
  width:100%;
  height:55px;
}
.imagen{
  position:relative;
  left:0%;
}
.tabla{
  position:relative;
  top: 1%;
  left:8%;
  width:90%;
  height:90%;
  word-wrap:break-word;
    word-break:normal;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
#referencia{
  margin:auto;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  cursor:pointer;
}
summary{
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:1em;
}
details{
  background-color:#DCDAD8;
  padding:2px;
}
.programa{
  position:relative;
  width:98%;
  margin:top;
  background-color:#C1BCB7;
  opacity:0.9;
  text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid #959391;
}
.hijo{
  position:relative;
  width:96%;
  margin:top;
  background-color:#CDCBC9;
  opacity:0.9;
  text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid #959391;
  margin:auto;
  padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
    <!-- SCRIPTS JS-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" action="pedir.php" id="formulario">
      <!--<?php
      $programas=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM programas");
      /*while ($prog=mysqli_fetch_array($programas)) {
        echo "<details class='programa'>";
        echo "<summary>";
        echo $prog['nombre_prog'];
        echo "</summary>";
        echo "<input type='text' id='bus1' data-bus1='" . $prog['id_prog'] . "'>";
        echo "<section id='categorias'></section>";
        echo "</details>";
      }*/
      ?>-->
      <input type='text' id='bus1' data-bus1='1'>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

No puedo usar var data=$(form).serialize(); debido a que necesito que también me envíe el id del programa a pedir.php; por favor, si alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradecería.

Por si acaso, aquí está pedir.php:

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
$categorias=$_POST['categoria'];
$id=$_POST['id'];
if (isset($_POST['categoria'])) {
    $productos=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE sub_categoria_prod LIKE '$categorias' GROUP BY sub_categoria_prod");
        while($prod=mysqli_fetch_array($productos)){
            echo "<details class='hijo'>";
            echo "<summary>";
            echo $prod['sub_categoria_prod'];
            echo "</summary>";
            $sub_categoria=$prod['sub_categoria_prod'];
            $id=$prog['id_prog'];
            $informacion=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE sub_categoria_prod='$sub_categoria' AND id_prog='$id' AND(nombre_prod LIKE '%$buscar%' OR sibol_prod LIKE '%$buscar%')");
            while ($i=mysqli_fetch_array($informacion)) {
                echo "<table border='1'class='tabla'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Nombre del producto (SIBOL).</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'><strong>" . $i['sibol_prod'] . "</strong></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Nombre comercial del producto.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['nombre_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Calidad.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['calidad_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Generalidades.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['generalidades_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Requisitos generales.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['re_generales_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Requisitos espec&iacute;ficos.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['re_espe_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Empaque y rotulado.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['empaque_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Presentaci&oacute;n.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['presentacion_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Imagen de referencia.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'><img src='" . $i['imagen_prod'] . "' id='referencia'></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table>";
            }
            echo "</details>";
        }
    }else{
        $productos=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM productos GROUP BY sub_categoria_prod WHERE id_prog='$id'");
        while($prod=mysqli_fetch_array($productos)){
            echo "<details class='hijo'>";
            echo "<summary>";
            echo $prod['sub_categoria_prod'];
            echo "</summary>";
            $categoria=$prod['sub_categoria_prod'];
            $id=$prog['id_prog'];
            $informacion=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE sub_categoria_prod='$categoria' AND id_prog='$id'");
            while ($i=mysqli_fetch_array($informacion)) {
                echo "<table border='1'class='tabla'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Nombre del producto (SIBOL).</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'><strong>" . $i['sibol_prod'] . "</strong></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Nombre comercial del producto.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['nombre_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Calidad.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['calidad_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Generalidades.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['generalidades_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Requisitos generales.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['re_generales_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Requisitos espec&iacute;ficos.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['re_espe_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Empaque y rotulado.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['empaque_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Presentaci&oacute;n.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['presentacion_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Imagen de referencia.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'><img src='" . $i['imagen_prod'] . "' id='referencia'></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table>";
            }
            echo "</details>";
        }
        echo "</details>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Porque tienes 2 llamadas ajax?

Comment: ¿Te sale algún error en la consola? Tienes un event.preventDefault(); que no debería ir ahí me parece.

Comment: La primera llamada AJAX, es para que traiga la información consultada sólo cuando el keyup se cumpla; y no me sale error. Así como en ele ejemplo, no me sale nada, no me toma el texto ingresado en el input.

Comment: que quieres hacer con esos dos ajax? , en realidad no le veo mucho sentido.

Comment: Lo que quiero, es que al ingresar un texto en el input, me llame vaya llamando los registros. Quiero hacer una búsqueda de datos en tiempo real.

Comment: Estás pidiendo un respuesta del servidor, esa "respuesta" la estas pidiendo de pedir.php, una respuesta del servidor es el `echo` de php, no crees que teniendo tantos `echo` por eso no te esté funcionando, aparte de que estas utilizando 2 AJAX que se dirigen a la misma página.

Answer (score 0):

Mira te recomiendo que intentes de está manera:

```
$("#bus1").on("keyup", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el=$("#bus1");
    var data=el.text();
    var ficha=el.data("bus1"); // en caso de que sea el atributo data-bus1
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"JSON",
        data: {id:ficha}, //solo te envia el parametro ID
        success: function(data) {
            obtener_datos();
        }
   });
```

Comment: ¿Para qué es la e en esta parte: function(e)?

Comment: Ya lo intenté, pero no me hace nada. Intenté con un alert(ficha) para saber si lo toma, pero no aparece.

Comment: Puedes seguir este fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mytxbkgo/ donde se ve que esta enviando el id aunque no siempre responderá el valor